# How to transitive get a list of libraries on which a certain project depends?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm primarily interested in this issue for projects built on the basis of the *stack*.

I managed to solve this problem by writing a script that analyzes the output of the command like `ghc-pkg field SOMEPKG hs-libraries` etc.

But this approach is rather slow, mainly due to the use of *stack* command for extract information from a project.

Is there another way to solve this issue without using a lot of tools?

---

**EDIT**

---

This is draft of script.

```
main = do
    pkgSet <- newIORef . asHashSet $ mempty
    libSet <- newIORef . asHashSet $ mempty
    let proc ghcId pkgId = do
            guard =<< (liftIO . map (pkgId `notMember`) . readIORef $ pkgSet)
            liftIO . modifyIORef pkgSet $ insertSet pkgId

            libDir1 <- lineToText <$> inproc "ghc-pkg"
                ["--simple-output", "field", pkgId, "dynamic-library-dirs"]
                (pure "")
            libDir2 <- lineToText <$> inproc "ghc-pkg"
                ["--simple-output", "field", pkgId, "library-dirs"] (pure "")
            libDir <- select . filter (not . null) $ [libDir1, libDir2]
            lib <- select =<< (map (words . lineToText) $ inproc "ghc-pkg"
                ["--simple-output", "field", pkgId, "hs-libraries"] (pure ""))
            let libPath = asText . repack $ repack libDir
                      </> (shlibPrefix ++ repack lib ++ "-" ++ repack ghcId)
                      <.> shlibSuffix

            guard =<< (liftIO . map (libPath `notMember`) . readIORef $ libSet)
            guard =<< (liftIO . doesFileExist . repack $ libPath)
            liftIO . modifyIORef libSet $ insertSet libPath

            dep <- select =<< (map (words . lineToText) $ inproc "ghc-pkg"
                ["--simple-output", "field", pkgId, "depends"] (pure ""))
            proc ghcId dep
    sh $ do
        ghcPkgPath <- lineToText <$> inshell "stack path --ghc-package-path" (pure "")
        export "GHC_PACKAGE_PATH" ghcPkgPath

        ghcVer <- lineToText <$> inshell "stack exec -- ghc --numeric-version" (pure "")
        let ghcId = "ghc" ++ ghcVer

        [pkg, ver] <- words . lineToText <$> inshell "stack list-dependencies" (pure "")
        let pkgId = pkg ++ "-" ++ ver
        proc ghcId pkgId
    -- processing libSet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ stack list-dependencies
MonadPrompt 1.0.0.5
MonadRandom 0.4
StateVar 1.1.0.1
...
```

For cabal projects try `cabal freeze --help`

Comment: First of all, I need to closure this set. Second, I do not need package names, I need a list of libraries in these packages with paths to them. `stack list-dependencies` it's just first stem in my script.

Comment: stack list-dependencies does yield all dependencies, so it shouldn't be necessary to recurse.  You will indeed need to consult ghc-pkg for the library path.

Comment: @freestyle then it's unclear what you're asking. "list of libraries in these packages": do you mean list of modules? Every package has at most one library. Your question doesn't mention paths at all